# problem in apex pagemessages on some condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, page-messages

i want to set the error message on page for below cases....

if i click on SAVE button error message should display...
Like "you have not selected any contact"

i have list of contacts and select checkbox to select that contacts...

```
 apex code:(short code method only)

  public void save(){

    for(contact c : conlist){
       if(c.selected == false){
          ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'SELECT CONTACT FIRST');
          ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
      }
    }
```

**NOW, the problem is message is showing properly but when i select and press save record is saving...
    and again error message is coming ...select contact first..
i think this is coming because of another contacts whose checkbox is false...
now i want after saving record if any one checkbox is true...then message should not be appear...
how i do this....Please help me out?....**

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code to check first if any contact has been selected before adding your error to the page

```
    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'SELECT CONTACT FIRST');
    Boolean atLeast1Contact = false;  // to check if a at least one contact is selected 
    for(contact c : conlist)
    {
       if(c.selected)
       {
          atLeast1Contact = true;
          break;
       }
    }

    if(!atLeast1Contact)
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
```